# Stuck at finding coefficients of generating functions.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Problem statement:

> Show that the number of r-combinations of specification $2^m1^{n-2m}$ is $$\sum_k {{m}\choose {k}}{{n-m-k}\choose{r-2k}}$$

I have found the generating function which is $(1+t+t^2)^m(1+t)^{n-2m}$, but I cannot proceed further to find the general coefficient.

I know the combinatorial proof for this question, I am specifically wanting to practice using generating functions. Any hint will also suffice.

I have tried using the geometric series formula and then Taylor expansion but could not proceed further.

Edit: The particular specification given here means there are objects of m kind with 2 of each kind and (n-2m) remaining objects that are distinct.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what you mean by "r-combinations of specification $2^m1^{n-2m}$" (This may very well be due to my limited knowledge). Can you please pose the combinatorial question in words?

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal 'r-combinations' means combinations of r elements and the particular specfication given here means objects of m kind with 2 of each kind and (n-2m) remaining objects that are distinct.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "objects of m kind with 2 of each kind"? Do you mean that there are 2m objects where each object has an identical partner?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 yes

Comment: Maybe use $1+t+t^2=(1-t^3)/(1-t)$?

Comment: I have mentioned that using 'geometric series formula' I could not go further. It can help finding specific terms but not the general term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^r]$ which denotes the coefficient of $x^r$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}=[x^r](1+x)^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain for non-negative integers $n\geq 2m$ and $r\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^m}&\color{blue}{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m-k}{r-2k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}[x^{r-2k}](1+x)^{n-m-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^r](1+x)^{n-m}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^r](1+x)^{n-m}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^m\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[x^r](1+x)^{n-2m}\left(1+x+x^2\right)^m}
> \end{align*}
>   and we conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m-k}{r-2k}\right)x^r
> =(1+x)^{n-2m}\left(1+x+x^2\right)^m
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (2) we factor out terms independent of $k$  by using the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and applying the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (3) we apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand $$(1+t+t^2)^m=\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}(1+t)^i(t^2)^{m-i}=\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}\Biggl(\sum _{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j}t^j1^{i-j}\Biggr)t^{2m-2i}=\\\sum_{i=0}^m\sum _{j=0}^i\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{j}t^{j+2m-2i}$$

On the other $$(1+t)^{n-2m}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2m}\binom{n-2m}{k}t^k1^{n-2m-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2m}\binom{n-2m}{k}t^k$$

Now, let's look at the sum representation we found for $(1+t+t^2)^m$ first (since it's the scarier looking one) and try to simplify it. Suppose we can rewrite this sum as $$\sum_pa_pt^p$$ That would be very convenient as this is a nice single sum rather than a double sum. To do that, we need to find $a_p$ in general. Looking at the original double sum we can see that we can find $a_p$ by finding all pairs of $j$ and $i$ such that $j\leq i$ and $j+2m-2i=p$- then, calculate for each pair, $\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{j}$, and sum all of these binomial products up. Suppose for our (fixed) $p$ we also fixed $i$ at some value between $0$ and $m$. Well, in that case $j$ could take on at most one value- that would be $p+2i-2m$. We say "at most" because $j$ also needs to be $\leq i$, i.e., $p+2i-2m\leq i\implies i\leq 2m-p$. Don't forget though that $j$ also has to be $\geq 0$- this means $p+2i-2m\geq 0\implies i\geq m-\frac{p}{2}$ ($j$ will always be an integer so we won't worry about that). So if we vary $i$ between $0$ and $m$, $i$ contributes to the coefficient, $a_p$, iff $m-\frac{p}{2}\leq i\leq 2m-p$, and when that *is* the case, $i$ contributes exactly $\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{p+2i-2m}$ to $a_p$.

In other words, $$a_p=\sum_{i=m-\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\rfloor}^{2m-p}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{p+2i-2m}$$

What are the possible values $p$ can take? Well, for each $p$ there must exist $i$ and $j$ in the original double sum's index so that $p=j+2m-2i$ so $p=j+2m-2i\leq i+2m-2i=2m-i\leq 2m$. Also $p=j+2m-2i\geq 0+2m-2i=2m-2i\geq 2m-2m=0$. So $p$ ranges from $0$ to $2m$.

Overall we have that $$(1+t+t^2)^m=\sum_{p=0}^{2m}a_pt^p$$  where, for each $p$  $$a_p=\sum_{i=m-\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\rfloor}^{2m-p}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{p+2i-2m}$$

Time to tackle the big boi.

Now we need to find a nice single sum representation for $(1+t+t^2)^m(1+t)^{n-2m}$. Well, we have a nice(ish) single sum for each of the terms individually- let's try smashing them together.

$$(1+t+t^2)^m(1+t)^{n-2m}=\Biggl(\sum_{p=0}^{2m}a_pt^p\Biggr)\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2m}\binom{n-2m}{k}t^k\Biggr)=\sum_{p=0}^{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2m}a_p\binom{n-2m}{k}t^{p+k}$$

Now, we run the same trick again and suppose that this double sum has some single sum expression like $$\sum_qb_qt^q$$

To find $b_q$ here, we need find pairs of $p$ and $k$ such that $p+k=q$, $0\leq p\leq 2m$, and $0\leq k\leq n-2m$. Now, suppose we fix some $p$ between $0$ and $2m$. Then $k$, again, has at most one value, i.e, $q-p$, and this one value is only valid if $0\leq k\leq n-2m \implies 0\leq q-p \leq n-2m \implies q-n-2m\leq p\leq q$. This gives us that $$b_q=\sum_{p=q-n-2m}^qa_p\binom{n-2m}{q-p}$$

Again, we can refer to the initial double sum to see that $p+k$ will always vary between $0$ and $n$, so $q$ varies between $0$ and $n$.

This all means: $$(1+t+t^2)^m(1+t)^{n-2m}=\sum_{q=0}^nb_qt^q$$

where, for each $q$  $$b_q=\sum_{p=q-n-2m}^qa_p\binom{n-2m}{q-p}$$

The $b_q$ are the coefficients we desire. To simplify (it's really just making things messier) plug in the general single sum expression for $a_p$  $$b_q=\sum_{p=q-n-2m}^q\Biggl(\sum_{i=m-\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\rfloor}^{2m-p}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{p+2i-2m}\Biggr)\binom{n-2m}{q-p}=\\\sum_{p=q-n-2m}^q\sum_{i=m-\lfloor\frac{p}{2}\rfloor}^{2m-p}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{p+2i-2m}\binom{n-2m}{q-p}$$

After some checking now, I'm pretty sure the working is correct *but* given the number of mistakes I made writing this, there's still a good chance I messed up somewhere. Regardless, this is basically how you can find the coefficients in general. You'll always end up with a double sum, like the final expression for $b_q$, so you'll probably need to pull out some nifty binomial identities or something to simplify it down to the single sum your question asks for. Or just look at Markus' *way* simpler answer.